# Css3 :empty selector acting strange with multiple class divs

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems trying to use the css3 :empty selector. My goal is to only display the contents of children .showme div when the parent .showhim div is hovered. Only when there is content to show. (Within the .showme-wrapper div).

However the fiddle below shows the .showme-wrapper displays even though it shouldn't because it empty:

https://jsfiddle.net/jzcm9uen/3/

If any anyone could help me hide this .showme-wrapper when it is empty, I'd be so grateful!

Code:

```css
.showme {
 width: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0px;
 min-height: 0px;
 max-height: 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
 transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

.showme-wrapper {
 display: block;
 width: 168px;
 height: initial;
 max-height: 150px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

 .showme-wrapper:empty {
  display: none;
 }

 .showhim:hover .showme {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown showhim">
 <p class="sidebar-title">I shouldn't show</p>
  <div class="showme">
   <div class="showme-wrapper">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown showhim">
    <p class="sidebar-title">I should show</p>
  <div class="showme">
   <div class="showme-wrapper">
              <p >Content</p>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

> The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at all. Only element nodes and text (**including whitespace**) are considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether an element is considered empty or not.

You have whitespace between `<div class="showme-wrapper">` and `</div>`. You'll need to remove it for the element to be considered `:empty`.

Comment: Thank you! This was Completely overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

The :empty selector matches every element that has no children (including text nodes). just remove the space in the `.showme-wrapper` div check with below fiddle or snippet

https://jsfiddle.net/jzcm9uen/5/

```css
.showme {
   text-align:center;
   width: 150px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0px;
   min-height: 0px;
   max-height: 0px;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

.showme-wrapper {
   display: block;
   width: 168px;
   height: initial;
   max-height: 150px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

.showme-wrapper:empty {
   display: none;
}
.showme-wrapper p{
   text-align: center;
}

.showhim {
   text-align: center;
}
.showhim:hover .showme {
   height: auto;
   max-height: 100px;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown showhim">
   <p class="sidebar-title">I shouldn't show</p>
   <div class="showme">
  <div class="showme-wrapper"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown showhim">
   <p class="sidebar-title">I should show</p>
   <div class="showme">
 <div class="showme-wrapper">
    <p >Content</p>
 </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:empty` doesn't match what you intuitively think it would/should match. Here are 4 examples:

```
<!-- These AREN'T :empty element: they contain whitespace
     (either carriage return or space but tab is also whitespace -->
<div class="showme-wrapper">
</div>
<div class="showme-wrapper"> </div>

<!-- These are :empty elements -->
<div class="showme-wrapper"></div>
<div class="showme-wrapper"
></div>
```

Comment: Thanks :). Didn't even occur to me that white space would be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Although your main problem has been solved and you are not using jQuery in question, but if you would like to use jQuery for solution in same situation, it would be helpful. Because the parent elements can not be targeted by using css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.showme-wrapper:empty').closest('.showhim').empty();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind for future development.